# How to save point ID when extracting values from bands?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have vector points that have some external IDs. I would like the point ID column to appear in the result table after extracting spectral values from the bands. 'Latitude', 'longitude', 'time' and '.geo' columns can be skipped, but I see that they are mandatory from the getRegion() function.

```
var points = [ee.Geometry.Point(-77.64, 37.51),
              ee.Geometry.Point(-77.66, 37.53),
              ee.Geometry.Point(-77.65, 37.52),
              ee.Geometry.Point(-77.68, 37.52),
              ee.Geometry.Point(-77.62, 37.54)];
var table = ee.FeatureCollection(points);

// external points ID
var dict = {oid:[101, 102, 103, 104, 105]};
var table = table.set(dict);

var data = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-04-01')
              .filterBounds(table)
              .getRegion(table, 30);

var keys = ee.List(data.get(0));
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(data.slice(1).map(function(singleData){
  singleData = ee.List(singleData);
  var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, singleData);
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point([dict.get('longitude'), dict.get('latitude')]);
  return ee.Feature(point, dict);
}));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: featureCollection,
  description: 'CSV'
});
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/45e8ceec3234adb13b68d07100ef7b58)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably missed the function reduceRegion(s), which allows you to get the data from the image and data points in the way you describe you want it.

But first, you now set the property of the feature collection instead of the property to each individual feature. There are multiple ways to tweak that, but here is an example:

```
// set the external point id to each individual feature
var dict = ee.List([101, 102, 103, 104, 105]);
var table = table.map(function(feat){
  var sampleID = ee.Number.parse(feat.id());
  return feat.set('oid', dict.get(sampleID));
});
```

Then you can import the image data and map over each image. By using reduceRegions, each feature of the collection will keep its original properties and the reducer output values of each band will be added as a property:

```
// map over the images and use reduceRegions() to extract data
var featureCollection = data.map(function(image){
  var dataOutput = image.reduceRegions(table, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30);
  return dataOutput;
}).flatten();
```

Use flatten to rework the collection of collections (which is the actual output) into a collection of the features you want. You can set additional properties such as the time from the image if you map over the 'dataOutput'. See an example in the [complete script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4ff6c94ebcd8c62879020e7b59c251ca).

Comment: I noticed a difference in the result values between your and my code, e.g. average band values B01: 2606 vs 2596, B04: 2651 vs 2640 (based on these same points). Not all values differ, some are the same in both cases. What is the reason for this and which version is the right one?

Comment: It is probably a result of how the GEE handles scale and projection, or change the reducer to `ee.Reducer.first()`, as a mean reducer takes the mean value of pixels within distance of scale and the point.